# Installed Xdebug but I cant find it in phpinfo

Tags: php, xdebug, homestead

I've installed Xdebug but cant find it in `phpinfo()` output.

I am operating according to https://xdebug.org/wizard.php:

Tailored Installation Instructions
Summary

```
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: FPM/FastCGI
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 7.2.14-1
Zend API nr: 320170718
PHP API nr: 20170718
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
OPcache Loaded: no
Configuration File Path: /etc/php/7.2/fpm
Configuration File: /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/lib/php/20170718
```

Instructions

```
Download xdebug-2.7.0.tgz
Install the pre-requisites for compiling PHP extensions.
On your Ubuntu system, install them with: apt-get install php-dev autoconf automake
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.7.0.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-2.7.0

Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize).

As part of its output it should show:

Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718

If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.
Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/20170718
Edit /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
Restart the webserver
```

**restart php and nginx, it still doesn't work.**

When I execute `php -m|grep xdebug` it returns:

> Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/2017/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_post_startup_cb

I don't know what's the `zend_post_startup_cb`; I can't find any information in website.

Comment: I am facing the issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: See if these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355045/xdebug-so-undefined-symbol-zend-ce-error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365425/installing-xdebug-on-centos7-i-get-error-undefined-symbol-compiler-globals, https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=916, https://serverfault.com/questions/977257/unable-to-install-xdebug-undefined-symbol-zend-post-startup-cb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to install from this

```
sudo apt-get install php-xdebug
```

You may find the xdebug.ini here (for php version 7.2)

```
vi /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini //zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

[image]
[image]

---

You may get the details on this reference link http://www.dieuwe.com/blog/xdebug-ubuntu-1604-php7

Comment: You wrote "You may find the xdebug.so here" but you put the path to /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

and follow its instructions. I have tried compiling xdebug in many ways and PECL was the only one it worked with